# upgraded SQL server does not let me connect to the database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I had SQl Sever 2008 R2 Express on my production server and i upgraded it to SQl Server 2008 Web Edition. Even since i upgraded my websites do not get connected to database. I was wondering what should be changing to connect to the databases. This is a Website in VS 2008.

This is the part of the code where i have the connection string.

```
connstring = "Data Source=198.57.59.70;Initial Catalog=Tracking;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
```

I get the error when connecting to database as "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections."

Can someone suggest where i am doing wrong, Please!!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What kind of error are u getting and in what line of code?

Comment: I have a login page. Login fails because of the error "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. "

Comment: Are you sure your instance name didn't change?  If you upgraded it could have a new instance name and/or no default instance set

Comment: @JNK Currently there is only one instance! That is "MSSQLServer".

Comment: So have you tried connecting to `198.57.59.70\MSSQLServer`?

Comment: @JNK, Yes i did and i get the same error. :-( And i want you to know that when i have just the server name "198.57.59.70", the debug mode in the production server works like a charm but the live website does not connect to the database. I thought this might give you a better idea.

Comment: @Ram Then my meager connection troubleshooting skills are spent. Good luck!

Comment: @JNk "Login failed for user 'COMM\IWPD_3" is what i get on the live website when i just the server ip address as a data source!

Comment: Can you reach the sql server from the live server. Ping and the like. Then telnet into the port. This may not be a SQL problem.

Comment: Check in SQL Server Configuration Manager that the TCP/IP protocol is enabled.

Comment: @Rikalous Yes, its enabled.. :-(

Comment: The instance name isn't in the datasource part of the connection string.